# Passing argument to a web application from tomcat 6.0.35

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat6

I need to pass an argument from tomcat server to my webapplication to load my configuration file dynamically according to the environment in which i am deploying that . I wanted to know how do i declare the -D argument as parameter in tomcat from the tomcat web page.

```
Tomcat version : 6.0.35
Java  version : 6
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

set your parameter in using `set JAVA_OPTS =-Dparam=value` and put in `setenv.bat` file in tomcats bin directory

Comment: is there no way to set from the tomcat server home page as like we do for websphere / weblogic

Comment: I dont find setenv.bat in tomcat/bin folder and also i need to know how to pass this argument from eclipse

Comment: if not found then create it, it will be considered automatically, in eclipse go to  your `run configuration > arguments> program argument` and specify here only `-Dparam=value`

Comment: Hi @Nirmal, I have done what you have suggested me , i have created a `setenv.bat` in tomcat/bin and hav provided `set JAVA_OPTS= -Denv=test` and i am trying to access the variable from my properties load class as `System.out.println("============================== Trying to access argument =======================================");
   System.out.println("----- Argument env  value   == "+System.getProperty("env"));` but is returning me "null"

Comment: did you executed this code in tomcat? or main method?, and are testing it on windows?

Comment: i have executed that in tomcat in a windows machine . I have made a war of my project and deployed that in the tomcat server instance

Comment: try setting `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dparam=value` in catalina.bat

Comment: I have installed the tomcat server from exe , catalina.bat will only be in the binary package , i have only these file in my /bin folder `bootstrap.jar
setenv.bat
tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat6.exe
Tomcat6w.exe`

Comment: Do u have any means that we can add that from the tomcat home page , the page which we get when we start the tomcat service and access [http://localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9188/discussion-between-sundhar-and-nirmal-think-beyond)

Comment: i have a <listener> class defined in my web xml, so when the server starts before my application loads that will trigger the class. In that i need to get that argument and also i cannot send the argument from eclipse , in the 'run configurations > Arguments under program arguments i have "start", but if add "start -Denv = test"
the server is not starting

Comment: sorry my mistake, put in vm argument not program argument

Comment: From eclipse is it working fine now , i have put that in vm argument just thinking of trying it and it worked . but how to pass it in the tomcat service is where i m struggling now.

Comment: i never used tomcat with installer, what can i do with binary bundle that i have suggested you. you can do one thing (i know its poor suggestion) set your environment variable as you set `JAVA_HOME` and in your code get it by `System.getenv("MY_VARIABLE");`